# What is the proper variable encapsulation in zabbix_sender for variable as host?

Tags: zabbix

I'm trying to iterate over a list with ip addresses in conjunction with zabbix_sender like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat list.txt | while read card
do
echo $card
zabbix_sender -z 10.160.0.121 -s $card -k receive.power1 -o $rx1
zabbix_sender -z 10.160.0.121 -s 172.16.1.116 -k receive.power1 -o $rx1
done​
```

The list.txt just consists of:
172.16.1.116
172.16.1.117
172.16.1.118
172.16.1.119
etc.

Upon executing the script, the response is as follows:

172.16.1.116 (from echo $card just for checking proper content)

info from server: "processed: 0; failed: 1; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.0022" sent:1; skipped:0; total:1
info from server: "processed: 1; failed: 0; total: 1; seconds spent: 0.0065" sent:1; skipped:0; total:1

So zabbix_sender with variable $card fails and zabbix_sender with plain IP address works.
Could someone enlighten me on how to encapsulate this variable properly if bare $card variable in the zabbix_sender syntax is not working?

I've tried $("card"), ${"card"}, ($card), "($card)"
The manual does not describe in any way shape or form the use of variables in zabbix_sender, oddly enough the -o $rx1 as variable works like a charm and is correctly called as such.
I've omitted how i obtain the value for $rx1 since that works and for clarity.

Comment: you can also use `--input-file` in Zabbix Sender to send multiple items at the same time

Comment: Thanks for your input, i've fixed it by not reading an external file with IP addresses, but placed the IP addresses into a variable, strangely enough the output was exactly the same, but zabbixsender somehow accepted this as a valid IP address.